# How do you solve this differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics

Though I've read questions on this site and really appreciate the quality of the answers, this is my first question, so I hope it follows the site's guidelines.

When working with potential energy curves from physics, I came across the equation

$a(x(t)) = 6 x(t) + 5$

where $a(x(t))$ denotes acceleration as a function of position, and position is a function of time.

I was wondering how one would solve this equation, if possible, to find the particle in question's trajectory as a function of time, i.e. let $x = x(t)$ and solve the equation given that $a(t) = x''(t)$.

Comment: To clarify, I'm trying to solve the above equation for a function x(t), the particle's trajectory.

Comment: Are you using "$a(x(t))$" and "$a(t)$" to mean the same thing, i.e., "particle's acceleration when the particle is at position $x(t)$, which occurs at time $t$"?

Answer (score 2):

We can rewrite the ODE as:

$$x'' -6x = 5$$

The homogeneous solution is found by noting:

$$m^2 - 6 = 0 \rightarrow m_{1,2} = \pm ~ \sqrt{6}$$

This gives:

$$x_h(t) = c_1 e^{\sqrt{6} t} + c_2 e^{-\sqrt{6} t}$$

For the particular, we choose $x_p = a$, and substitute into the ODE and arrive at $a = -\dfrac{5}{6}$.

Our final solution is:

$$x(t) = x_h(t) + x_p(t) = c_1 e^{\sqrt{6} t} + c_2 e^{-\sqrt{6} t} -\dfrac{5}{6}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Doesn't your rewrite of the equation assume that a(x(t)) = x''(t)? I'm having trouble seeing the basis for this assumption; I don't think it follows from the fact that a(t) = x''(t), since a is no longer a function of t but a functional of x(t).

Comment: @Piyush I think your equation should read $a(t)=\dots$ instead of $a(x(t))=\dots$.

Comment: @Piyush The acceleration should be a function of time, not position. The particle could pass through the same position twice with different accelerations, for example.

Comment: Ah, but this is exactly where my confusion lies. In many cases and indeed the one that led me to this problem, force is a function of position, such as when dealing with springs (Hooke's law states F_s = -kx for position x and constant k). Newton's second law tells us that acceleration is therefore a function of position. My question is: is it possible to find how the position  itself varies with time?

Comment: True, but in my case the force and therefore acceleration varies with position. Can one solve for the position as a function of time, given the definition that a(t) = x''(t)? I don't think this implies that a(x(t)) = x''(t).

Comment: @Piyush Regarding your Newton's law remark. Force is a function of position, but you require more than just the position to specify the force, so it is not solely a function of position. In fact, it is a function of time. So by your logic, acceleration is also a function of time, and everything is good.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is 
$$
\frac{d^2 x}{d t^2} = 6 x  + 5 \tag 1$$

Since the equation is *linear* second order, the solution is of the form 
$$
x = A + B_1 e^{a_1 t}  + B_2 e^{a_2 t}$$
Differentiating
$$
x'= a_1 B_1 e^{a_1 t} + a_2 B_2 e^{a_2 t} \\
x''= a_1^2 B_1 e^{a_1 t} + a_2^2 B_2 e^{a_2 t}
$$
Substituting in (1) we get
$$
a_1^2 B_1 e^{a_1 t} + a_2^2 B_2 e^{a_2 t} = 6 A + 6 B_1 e^{a_1 t}  +6  B_2 e^{a_2 t}+5 \tag 2$$
Comparing coefficients in (2) we get
$$
A = -5/6\\
a_1^2 = 6 \\
a_2^2 = 6
$$
If $a_1 = a_2$ then the two terms merge into one, so we pick $a_1 \neq a_2$ giving
$$
a_1 = + \sqrt{6}, ~~a_2 = - \sqrt{6}$$
Hence the general solution is
$$
x(t)= -5/6 + B_1 e^{\sqrt{6} t} + B_2 e^{-\sqrt{6} t}$$
If you know the initial position and initial velocity (or any two conditions) then you can find $B_1$ and $B_2$.

Comment: Hi @user44197, a suggestion: “Since the equation is [linear] and of second order then...”.

Comment: @pppqqq Thanks for pointing out. I have made the change.

Answer (score 1):

If I well understand the new wording of the question, a manner to solve the ODE is shown in attachment :

[image]